# How to use python to remove names from text using a separate file of name list

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I have Data in a format

DataFrame:-
ColA          ColB
Issue 1       Mr.Joy meets with Mr.Roy and then does not like each other.
Issue 2       Rahul says Hi
[image]

Expected output:-

ColA          ColB
Issue 1       Mr.xxx meets with Mr.xxx and then does not like each other.
Issue 2       xxx says Hi

[image: enter image description here too.]

I have a separate list:-

NameList
Roy
Joy
Rahul

using this List as a stopword would like to remove or replace with xxx in Df.ColB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Please also try to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) your question first, and try to write some kind of code. If you can't even come up with a general approach, then you don't have a question that can be answered here - this is not a discussion forum. Finally, make sure that you actually *ask a question*. You said what you want to do; why not just do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need a For loop and a regex to search and replace
Loop 1 will run for each sentence and search for NameList in each row and then regex to replace.